# python code for getting all the links from view source including all the tags

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

Can some one guide me, how to get all the links which are visible in view page source by using python. I wanted to retrieve all links from all tags (like link,a,img,css...everything).below is the code which i tried.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
r=requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)
soup.prettify()
for anchor in soup.find_all('a',href=True):
    print anchor['href']
for anchor in soup.find_all('link',href=True):
    print anchor['href']
for anchor in soup.find_all('img',src=True):
    print anchor['src']
for anchor in soup.find_all('script',src=Treu):
    print anchor['src']
```

like this i am able to get links from all tags,but not able to get the links from style sheet. for ex
   .bg {.bg {background: url(XXXX)}.

Comment: BeautifulSoup won't help you with that. Have you considered regular expressions? A note of warning too: if the javascript or the css are embedded in the HTML (so not in an external file), and they refer to other urls, you'll be missing that too right now with your current approach.

Answer (score 0):

BeautifulSoup can't parse JS code and CSS code. But you can use RegExp for this task.

Also, if you have a lot the same code use list, arrays and dict for it:

```
for anchor in soup.find_all('a',href=True):
    print anchor['href']
for anchor in soup.find_all('link',href=True):
    print anchor['href']
```

to:

```
for tag in ['a', 'link']:
    for anchor in soup.find_all(tag, href=True):
        print anchor['href']
```

Then you can easily change the code

Answer (score 0):

solution for  this `re.findall('url\(([^)]+)\)',target_text)`

Comment: can you explain the cmd more?